# When a 'view.rx.isHidden' has changed, how can i emit a single to let annother view know, can i observe 'view.rx.isHidden'?

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I have a view A, click on a button to make it show or hide the way through RxSwift: `.bind(to: nearbyVc.view.rx.isHidden)` 
Now I want to monitor view A property`isHidden` and do something Other things, how can I make it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use your view as if it was a model. You are programmatically changing the `isHidden` property of the view when your model changes, so have those model changes also do the "other things".

So for example:

```
let validInput = textField.rx.text.map { $0.length > 0 }

validInput
    .map { !$0 }
    .bind(to: inputButton.rx.isHidden)
    .disposed(by: bag)

validInput
    .bind(onNext: { _ in /* do other thing */ })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

In the above `validInput` is the model.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ！